# -List property in cmdlet Get-WmiObject

Tags: windows, powershell, wmi, get-wmiobject

I know that `-List` gets the names of the WMI classes in the WMI repository namespace, but I don't really understand what it means in the following context:

```
(Get-WmiObject -list Win32_ShadowCopy).Create("C:\","ClientAcessible")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<sup>Note: The **CIM cmdlets have superseded the WMI cmdlets**, but the **answer applies somewhat analogously**, except that `Get-CimInstance` doesn't support `-List`, but there's a dedicated `Get-CimClass` cmdlet and the simplest way to invoke class methods is to *always* use the dedicated `Invoke-CimMethod` cmdlet.</sup>

---

```
(Get-WmiObject -list Win32_ShadowCopy).Create("C:\","ClientAcessible")
```

**uses the `-List` parameter to get access to the `Win32_ShadowCopy` *class***, so as to be able to then ***instantiate* it via its `.Create()` method, which requires *arguments***.

By contrast, instances of many WMI classes do *not* require arguments, so a simple `Get-WmiObject <class-name>` call is usually sufficient; e.g.:

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_ComputerSystem # no arguments needed; returns instance directly
```

[Ansgar Wiechers](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1630171/ansgar-wiechers) points out that **a simpler (and faster) way to obtain a WMI class is by casting its name to type accelerator `[wmiclass]`**, so the equivalent of your `-List`-based command is:

```
([wmiclass] Win32_ShadowCopy).Create("C:\","ClientAcessible")
```

That said, **the more PowerShell-like way to *invoke a method* on a WMI *class* is to use

`Invoke-WmiMethod`**. Again, the equivalent of the `-List`-based command is:

```
Invoke-WmiMethod Win32_ShadowCopy -Name Create -ArgumentList "C:\", "ClientAcessible"
```

---

**As for the *general* purpose of the `-List` parameter**:

Let's ask PowerShell's own help system, also available [online](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-wmiobject):

```
PS> Get-Help Get-WmiObject -Parameter List

-List [<SwitchParameter>]
    Gets the names of the WMI classes in the WMI repository namespace that is specified 
    by the Namespace parameter.

    If you specify the List parameter, but not the Namespace parameter, 
    Get-WmiObject uses the Root\Cimv2 namespace by default. 
    This cmdlet does not use the Default Namespace registry entry in the
    HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\WBEM\Scripting registry key 
    to determine the default namespace.
```

In other words: **`-List`'s purpose is to list (enumerate) WMI classes, optionally filtered by class-name pattern**:

- If you don't explicitly use `-NameSpace`, `ROOT\Cimv2` is assumed.
- The first positional parameter - `Win32_ShadowCopy` in your case - binds to the `-ClassName` (`-Class`) parameter, which in this case acts as a *filter*.

  - Since `Win32_ShadowCopy` is a *literal* class name, only that very class is matched, but you can use *wildcards* too (see below).

E.g., to find all WMI classes (in namespace `ROOT\Cimv2`) whose name contains the word `shadow`, use:

```
PS> Get-WmiObject -List -Class *shadow*


   NameSpace: ROOT\cimv2

Name                                Methods              Properties
----                                -------              ----------
Win32_ShadowProvider                {}                   {Caption, CLSID, Description, ID...}
Win32_ShadowCopy                    {Create, Revert}     {Caption, ClientAccessible, Count, Description...}
Win32_ShadowContext                 {}                   {Caption, ClientAccessible, Description, Differential...}
Win32_ShadowStorage                 {Create}             {AllocatedSpace, DiffVolume, MaxSpace, UsedSpace...}
Win32_ShadowVolumeSupport           {}                   {Antecedent, Dependent}
Win32_ShadowFor                     {}                   {Antecedent, Dependent}
Win32_ShadowOn                      {}                   {Antecedent, Dependent}
Win32_ShadowBy                      {}                   {Antecedent, Dependent}
Win32_ShadowDiffVolumeSupport       {}                   {Antecedent, Dependent}
```

Comment: Thanks, @AnsgarWiechers. I've added your tip to the answer.